# Rails 5.1 Webpacker – added moment.js via yarn – how to use package in old asset JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm new to webpacker and yarn. I installed successfully the package with:

> yarn add moment

*EDIT2:*

This is my import

```
# app/javascript/packs/application.js
import moment from 'moment/moment'
import 'moment/locale/de-ch'
```

**Problem: I can't use the "moment" package in my old JS asset files**

First works, the other not:

```
# in: app/javascript/packs/application.js
console.log('Log: ' + moment([2007, 0, 29]).toNow()) #=> Log: in 10 Jahren

# in app/*assets*/javascripts/application.js
console.log('Log2: ' + moment([2007, 0, 29]).toNow()) #=> Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined
```

*EDIT1:*

Here the key points of the installation process of webpacker:

1. in gemfile: **gem 'webpacker', github: 'rails/webpacker'**
2. Add this line to assets.rb: **Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')**
3. Add in %head of application.html.haml this: **= javascript_pack_tag 'application'**
4. Restart Rails server and start webpacker

Note: I upgraded my app from Rails 4.2 to 5.0 and later to 5.1; maybe something is missing in my app

Comment: I use moment.js in a regular asset JS-file: app/assets/javascript/<my_file>.coffee

Comment: Did you try `import { moment } from 'moment/moment'`?

Comment: @palma I did now; still the error

Comment: Do I have to include the old "asset"-tree to webpacker? I installed webpacker today and it's not an new rails app

Comment: Can you import any other component, library? How are you testing the import of moment, I've tried your second way and it works.

Comment: Maybe I missed something at the installation. I added *"= javascript_pack_tag 'application'"* to *application.html.haml* AND in assets.rb Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')"; webpacker is running **Do I have to do something else?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I thought this is a solution, but it's not: https://github.com/rails/webpacker#resolved-paths

In "/config/webpacker.yml" I added this:

```
# /config/webpacker.yml    
resolved_paths: ['app/assets']
```

An here I imported the files that use "moment.js":

```
# /app/javascript/packs/application.js
import 'javascripts/<folder>/<some_file_uses_moment>.coffee'
```

=> Still the error

Later I fount this article: 
http://samuelmullen.com/articles/embracing-change-rails51-adopts-yarn-webpack-and-the-js-ecosystem/

> What happened to the Asset Pipeline? Long story short: nothing. You
>   can still use the asset pipeline the way you always have – ”If you
>   like your asset pipeline, you can keep your asset pipeline”. That
>   includes the javascripts/ directory. You can even mix packaged files
>   with “pipelined” files in your views. **You just can’t include your
>   packaged files into your “pipelined” files; well, not easily.**

It seems I can't mix the "moment" package with "old" asset JS (?)

Answer (score 11):

I has a similar issue that momentjs was being used throughout the app/assets/javascript files and it was included via gem (actually, even worse, rails-assets). Looks like we both needed moment object to be available globally, not just inside the pack. So, the following fixed that for me and I'll keep it around until I get rid of app/assets/javascript files.

```
import moment from 'moment'

window.moment = moment
```

Comment: I have searched all over the place for an answer to this. Thanks for posting your fix!

Comment: Moved from sprockets to Webpacker in a newly updated Rails 6 app. This helped me. Thanks.